# Process doesnt pass arguments to SvcUtil

Tags: c#

I want my code to execute SvcUtil with some arguments, in order to generate proxy classes for a web service. All the WSDL and XSD files in the same folder. Because of this, WorkingDirectory is set to outputFolder, so that SvcUtil is executed from there, and hence the *.wsdl and *.xsd in the arguments.

```
private void GenerateClientProxy(string wsdlExePath, string outputFolder, string arguments, out string outputText)
{
    outputText = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        var p = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                WorkingDirectory = outputFolder,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = wsdlExePath,
                Arguments = arguments
            }
        };

        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.  
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();
        outputText = output;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

The values of:

wsdlExePath: 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\SvcUtil.exe"

outputFolder: "C:\Users\z6uke\Desktop\tinglysningen\autogenerated\"

arguments: 

"*.wsdl *.xsd /namespace:\"*,eTLService.WCF.eTL\" /output:\"C:\Users\z6uke\Desktop\tinglysningen\autogenerated\ElektroniskAkt.cs\""

The output is:

"Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool\r\n[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.18020]\r\nCopyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nIf you would like more help, type \"svcutil /?\"\r\n"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the argument string gets passed correctly? You can check by setting a breakpoint on `GenerateClientProxy`

Comment: I believe so. The values above are from Debug mode. Actually I used the Immediate window, but should be the same.

Comment: Are you escaping the backslashes in C:\Users\z6uke\Desktop\tinglysningen\autogenerated\ElektroniskAkt.cs\?

Comment: There are two backslashes in the paths. It seems that stackoverflow escapes them aswell, thats why we only see one.

Comment: it looks like /output was not a valid argument. It should have been /o instead. Thanks though @soumer!

Comment: it's always the little things ^^